# Property Group : pointing to non ID types

Tags: python, add-on

I'm working with CollectionProperty and PropertyGroup, and i have a few issues to store specific data (let's say an FCurve) :

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup
from bpy.props import *

class DS_KF(PropertyGroup):
    bl_label = "filtered keyframes"
    bl_idname = "ds.kf"

    fcurve : PointerProperty(type = bpy.types.Fcurve)
```

the DS_KF class is added to Window_manager Type as a collection Property :

```
def register(): 
    ...
    bpy.types.WindowManager.ds_keyframes = CollectionProperty(type = DS_KF)
```

In this case my property group won't register (i guess PointerProperty need to point on a ID type). However i thought i could change ":" for "=" and it did registered. But later on the script, while trying to iterate trough `bpy.context.window_manager.ds_keyframes[i].fcurve.keyframe_points` , i had this: `AttributeError: '_PropertyDeferred' object has no attribute 'keyframe_points'`

so i decided to put the fcurve in a list (maybe not the best idea):

```
class DS_KF(PropertyGroup):
    bl_label = "filtered keyframes"
    bl_idname = "ds.kf"

    kf = []
```

Then the issue came in my filtering function :

```
def filter() :

    window = bpy.context.window_manager
    window.ds_keyframes.clear()
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    
    for ob in scene.objects :
         ob.animation_data :
            if ob.animation_data and ob.animation_data.action:
                for fcurve in ob.animation_data.action.fcurves :
                    for kf in fcurve.keyframe_points :
                        if kf.select_control_point == True :
                            ds_kf = window.ds_keyframes.add()
                            ds_kf.fcurve = [fcurve]
                            
                            print(ds_kf.fcurve[0]) #This print works fine   

    for ds_kf2 in window.ds_keyframes : 
        print(ds_kf2.fcurve) #This returns an empty list : []
```

My list is emptied at some point so i can't access it later, and calling `window.ds_keyframes[i].fcurve[0]` will return an error (Index out of range).
I noticed then that .append function would give me better results, even if it's not recommended in term of performance :

```
ds_kf.fcurve.append(fcurve) #instead of ds_kf.fcurve = [fcurve]
```

BUT... while iterating into my for loops, i expected to have **several** `window.ds_keyframes[0], window.ds_keyframes[1]`. and in each one, to find only **one item** in each `window.ds_keyframes[i].fcurve` list : `window.ds_keyframes[i].fcurve[0]`

Not at all, every .fcurve list seem to be synchronized with each other, and i have now .fcurve[0] and .fcurve[1] keeping the data i wanted in the wrong place...

It has to be something about '=' or ':' in my property group..

I must be missing something. Any help is truly welcome !

Comment: Well, I think you answered your own question in the title : PointerProperty only works (reliably) with ID types. Using a list with custom types is mostly supported in the UI, but it's not "serializable" so you can't ever undo or redo, save then load your file or reliably use it in the operator logic system. You can circumvent these shortcoming most of the times by using string or integer lookups instead of pointers. The caveat is if you rename the target or change its order if it's in a list the link is lost.